# Troubles with submit_form with rvest

Tags: r, authentication, screen-scraping, rvest

I am having trouble trying to get submit form to work correctly. This is what I have below:

```
library(rvest)    

username<-abc
password<-111

url <-'https://www.puregym.com/members/'
session<-html_session(url)
form<-html_form(session)[[3]]
filled<-set_values(form, 
                   email = username,
                   pin=password)
submit_form(session,filled)
```

The form[[3]] is as below:.

```
<form> 'loginForm' (POST )
  <input hidden> 'associateAccount': false
  <input email> 'email': 
  <input password> 'pin': 
  <input submit> '': Login
```

and my output is:

```
    Submitting with 'NULL'
Error in xml2::url_absolute(form$url, session$url) : 
  Not compatible with STRSXP: [type=NULL].
```

I have seen errors relating to the second line but I believe that top line relating to there being a NULL value is there due to the nature of this form? The submit part of the form has no value and so it is not putting anything into it?

Would anyone have any idea how to get around this or perhaps do it as a POST through httr?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

it non standard form, you need to set missing POST url

```
form$url<- 'https://www.puregym.com/api/members/login/'
filled<-set_values(form, 
                   email = username,
                   pin=password
                   )
submit_form(session,filled)
```